# Stream folder on path and its subfolders Java

Tags: java, stream, subdirectory

I have a method which right now searches for a given path and gives back files according to a filter/predicate. Now I need to change it so it also searches the paths subfolders after files as well. Did anyone get a neat solution?

```
    private static List<FileInfo> listBackupFilesInLocalDir(String localPath, Predicate<String> fileNamePredicate) {
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get(localPath))) {
        return files.filter(p -> fileNamePredicate.test(p.getFileName().toString()))
                    .map(p -> new FileInfo(p.getFileName().toString(), p.toFile().length()))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error listing directories", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-

Comment: so as i understand i should only really need to change Files.list to Files.walk? @JBNizet

Comment: You would have to read the javadoc to understand what the two methods do, and try something on your own.